# SQL Server : Update order, Why does it work and can I trust it?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012

There is a "magic query" I don't understand why it's working using a temporary column I am updating a table and let it use the previous values it already calculated.

It sets the rolMul to be a rolling multiplication of the item till now.

Can I trust this method?

Why does it work in the first place?

If I can't trust it what alternatives can I use?

-- Create data to work on

```
select * into #Temp from (
select 1 as id, null as rolMul ) A
insert into #temp select 2 as id, null as rolMul  
insert into #temp select 3 as id, null as rolMul 
insert into #temp select 4 as id, null as rolMul  
insert into #temp select 5 as id, null as rolMul
```

------Here is the magic I don't understand why it's working -----

```
declare @rolMul int = 1
update #temp set @rolMul = "rolMul" = @rolMul * id from #temp

select * from #temp 

-- you can see it did what I wanted multiply all the previous values

drop table #temp
```

What bothers me is:

1. Why does it work? can I trust it to work?
2. What about the order? If
   the table was not ordered

   select * into #Temp from (
   select 3 as id, null as rolMul ) A
   insert into #temp select 1 as id, null as rolMul 
   insert into #temp select 5 as id, null as rolMul
   insert into #temp select 2 as id, null as rolMul
   insert into #temp select 4 as id, null as rolMul

   declare @rolMul int = 1
   update #temp set @rolMul = "rolMul" = @rolMul * id from #temp

   select * from #temp order by id
   drop table #Temp

   go

Comment: [Here is a bloggpost about running totals.](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals). What is said there applies to your case as we'll except there is no built in aggregate you can use in SQL Server 2012. Conclusion is don't trust the quirky update, use a cursor.

Comment: Mikael, this is what I thought as well, but it looks so tempting.

Comment: @marc_s this is what I though of as well. but it looks so promising.
It runs so much faster than cursor, maybe I can add clustered index or something?

Comment: If I add 
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX tempid 
    ON #Temp (id); 

it works on the unsorted as well
But I am afraid to use it in production enviroment :(

Comment: How many rows do you test on? What is the difference in duration between quirky update and a cursor for you?

Comment: On 280,000 records,
I get 0 seconds the "magic" way 
While cursor that does update record by record 
takes over 54 seconds.
And I would need to run it on millions of records

Comment: @MikaelEriksson As of SQL Server 2012 you can do this by a running sum of logarithms: `EXP(SUM (LOG(num)) OVER (ORDER BY num))` gives the correct result without invoking quirks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I can't trust it what alternatives can I use?

As of SQL Server 2012, you can use an efficient rolling sum of logarithms.

```
WITH tempcte AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    rolmul,
    EXP(SUM(LOG(id)) OVER (ORDER BY id)) AS setval
  FROM #Temp
)
UPDATE tempcte
SET rolmul = setval;
```

SQL Server 2012 introduces the [OVER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause to the [SUM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) function. [Ole Michelsen](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server-2012/) shows with a brief example how this efficiently solves the running total problem.

The [product law of logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities) says that the log of the product of two numbers is equal to the sum of the log of each number.

This identity allows us to use the fast sum to calculate multiplications at similar speed. Take the log before the sum and take the exponent of the result, and you have your answer!

SQL Server gives you [LOG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190319.aspx) and [EXP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179857.aspx) to calculate the [natural logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) (base *e*) and its exponential. It doesn't matter what base you use as long as you are consistent.

The [updatable common table expression](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/use-common-table-expressions-to-simplify-your-updates-in-sql-server/) is necessary because window expressions can't appear in the SET clause of an update statement.

The query is reliably correct for small numbers of rows, but will overflow very quickly. Try 64 rows of 2 and you'll bust the bigint!

In theory this should product the correct result as long as the ids are unique. In practice, I think your set of ids will always be small :-)

Comment: Nice. For performance reasons you should change your over clause to `OVER (ORDER BY id rows unbounded preceding`. The default is `range unbounded preceding` and because it behaves differently for duplicate id values it has to use a worktable as an intermediate when doing the sum. When using `rows` SQL Server only keeps one value (the total so far) in memory and uses that. To confirm that I am right about this you can do a test and have a look at the reads.

Comment: `STATISTICS IO` shows that both have a worktable but `rows unbounded preceding` has 0 extra reads. Interesting! The query actually only works properly if id is unique. Otherwise the rolmul column quietly accumulates a sum for each and jumps up for the next increment of id. I guess I have a lot more to learn about window functions.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson You'll hit numeric overflow with this query long before you get enough rows to worry about how long it takes! :-)

Comment: The  EXP(SUM(LOG( is a nice way to do mul for the values.
But I used Mul originally to just show a function that does not exist in SQL
My Actual problem is not mul but some kind of function can be using multiple variables...